# How can I identify a raid boss Pokémon from a regular one in my Pokémon bag?

Tags: pokemon-go

Let's say I have a Magikarp in my Pokémon bag and go to a raid where the raid boss is Magikarp. I then defeat the raid boss and capture it.

How do I identify which Magikarp in my Pokémon bag is the Pokémon from the raid battle?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/313463/what-do-the-caught-icons-represent/313474#313474)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming your older Magikarp were not caught in raids, you can also tell which one was caught in a raid by the fact that it will have been caught in a Premier ball.

Take two of my Magikarp for example:

[image: magikarp before raids]

The ball used to capture this Magikarp was a Pokéball.

[image: magikarp from raid]

However, the ball used to catch this Magikarp was a Premier ball, which you only are able to use when catching raid Pokémon.

Even if you catch 20 Magikarp and then a raid boss Magikarp in a single day, you'll be able to tell which one was the raid boss by checking what ball was used to capture it.

As discussed in the comments below, this is most useful if you only hang onto one or two Magikarp at a time. If you like to keep a lot of Magikarp on hand (I'm not judging), the easiest way to keep track of which is which might be to just give nicknames to the ones you want to differentiate from the rest.

Comment: This is true, but I find it tedious to go through every one of your Magikarps until you find one caught with a Premier ball.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi well if you try to find a Magikarp you caught in a raid more than a day after the fact, just using the Recent tab won't help, especially if you've caught other Magikarp in the meantime. The premier ball is the only indicator of a Pokémon being caught in a raid.

Comment: But at the same time, looking through all the Magikarps caught with premier balls, and you do a lot of raids, you won't be able to see which Magikarp is from your most recent raid. You could combine both methods and look for the most recent Magikarp caught with a premier ball.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi yes this is true. But if you are keeping *that* many Magikarp, why not just name them?

Comment: Naming them is a good idea. I was assuming that the OP had that many Magikarp because he couldn't find his newer ones. Also, Magikarps from raids are relatively high CP, so there is a good chance the OP does not transfer most of his/her Magikarp.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi fair enough, I added the nick naming suggestion to the answer

Answer (score 11):

Click on the "Recent" tab in the Pokémon Bag, and find your new Magikarp. It will be highlighted in light blue ([blue aura](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273028/what-is-the-blue-aura-around-my-pokemon)) and located in the top left. All recent catches are found there.

You can also look at the CP of the boss before capture, and then look for it when scrolling through all of your Magikarp.

The ball of the Pokémon captured in a raid will always be a premier ball, and the Pokéball used can be determined in each Pokémon's stats, as shown in Vemonus' answer.

Comment: I think this is the more actually useful answer for the question-as-stated (you _just_ completed a raid, how do you tell which one you received?).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, a newer way to tell if a Pokémon was caught via a raid is to use the "raid" filter<sup>1</sup>.

[image: Raid Filter]

---

<sup>1</sup> This filter will only work for Pokémon caught via raids after ~October 2020. I am not exactly sure how far back this filter goes, but the first Pokémon in this list was caught on 10/11/2020 and Pokémon caught in raids in August 2020 do not show up

Answer (score 0):

While the *Recent* sort order is definitely the easiest way to tell, you can also tell to some extent by simply paying attention to the CP of the Raid Boss as you capture it.  Most likely there will be only one Magikarp of that exact CP in your bag.  All Magikarp captured from raids will be [in the range of 104-125](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/raid-boss-list), as well, so even if you forgot to notice, you may be able to tell just from that range.

Further, Raid Boss Magikarp are level 20 (no matter your level, higher OR lower), and similar to Egg hatches will have IVs at least 10/10/10 or better (no stat under 10).  It's likely that you will not have more than one or two other exactly-level-20 Magikarp in your bag.  Combined with the date you captured it (which is displayed on the bottom of the Pokémon's page), the premier ball as noted in Vemonus' answer, and the location captured, you can narrow it down fairly easily.

Comment: This doesn't help if you can't remember the CP of the raid boss.  For example, my regular Magikarp was higher CP than the raid boss.  The main reason for this question, is that I forgot when the raid battle occurred and the CP of the raid boss.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Well, you can use any of the other suggestions too; you can look for CP 104-125 range Magikarp, in particular, as the raid capture will always be in that range.  (Note the "raid boss" is not what you capture; that has a much *higher* CP.)  You can at least narrow down to the ones in that CP range, and then look for Premier balls.